# Dependency injecting an ASP.NET Identity user (and unit testing)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I don't fully understand how to refactor my app to make it more testable.

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.0 (Razor Pages, if that matters).

**Current State:**

I have razor pages models that inject in my context (inherited from IdentityDbContext) and userManager:

```
public class DashboardModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<AVUser> _userManager;

    public DashboardModel(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<AVUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        AVUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        MyRepository myRepository = new MyRepository(_context, AVUser);

        // omitted - just getting data from the repository for use on the page

        return Page();
    }
```

I have repositories created who have constructors as the following:

```
public MyRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, AVUser user)
```

I never use the context directly in my Model classes and instead create repositories in the Model classes using the context passed in. In this case ApplicationDbContext is my EF Core context, and AVUser is my type of Identity User, defined as:

```
public class AVUser : IdentityUser
```

My DI is set up as:

```
// DB Setup
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


// Identity Setup
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<AVUser>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; 
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**What I don't understand**

I want to make my razor pages model classes unit testable without relying on the database or repository classes, mocking up the repository class, so I expect I have to remove the context from the constructor and instead created interfaces for my repositories and DI them.

However, I don't know how to DI in the user parameter for the Repository - how do I set up my service in Startup.cs so this can get passed in? Today to get the value for this, I run:

```
AVUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Comment: what does `public DashboardModel(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<AVUser> userManager)` look like?  When you say Model for your Razorpage, does that mean that's the object that gets passed in when your controller returns that view? so for example `return View("view.cshtml", dashBoardModelObject)` ?

Comment: I extended my question to include more code there. It's simply just a razor page .html.cs file that fetches some data from the repository for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inject your repositories in the DI container, IoC will automatically inject their dependencies like controllers and pages. so you just need to have a constructor like this in your repository class:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
private readonly UserManager<AVUser> _userManager;

public MyRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<AVUser> userManager)
{
    _context = context;
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

and then inject it to the container:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyRepository,MyRepository>();
```

and that's it.
remember to create an interface for your repository so you can inject different instances for either production or testing. Nonetheless, You shouldn't rely on DI for testing. If you are writing unit tests then create a test implementation for your MyRepository and simply instantiate it. If you are writing integration tests then you have to use a different `sturtup` class.

Comment: Thank you, I follow this, but one question - in this case I'm now having UserManager<AVUser> injected into the Repo instead of the AVUser object itself. I was thinking I would want to have AVUser passed to the repositories so that if I am leveraging my repositories outside the context of ASP.NET (say, in a console app to generate demo data), I can create an AVUser object in my console app and pass it in, and repo class does not have to run in the context of ASP.NET. Does that make sense?

Comment: And fair enough on the point about relying on DI for testing - as long as I convert to interfaces the DI doesn't matter for this, and I can still write my tests by having test objects!

Comment: technically, you shouldn't have any problem, however, you can work around that to, just have a AVUser registered in your DI container, which accepts 
UserManager<AVUser> in the constructor, then inject AVUser  into your repository. in either case you are good.